# Get current time in arduino 1.6.6

Tags: time, arduino

What method should I use to get the current time on arduino 1.6.6?

I tried to use DateTime, but that didn't work.
I tried to use the Time library (http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/time) but this doesn't seem to be compatible with arduino 1.6.6

Comment: that link doesn't work for me?

Comment: Do you want to obtain the time through serial communication or through internet (e.g. by using an Ethernet Shield)?

Comment: In the end I want to have an independent clock. This is however the goal of my miniproject, I'm not that close so far.

So initially I would right now already be happy to get the time in any possible way.

Comment: Add again - http://pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_Time.html

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the time and date you should have something that.. Keeps track of the time and date!

There are two ways to achieve this.

The first and most common is to use a real time clock (RTC). There are plenty of them, but I usually use the maxim ones. You can get one with internal or external crystal, with or without battery to keep the time... They usually interface to the microcontroller through a I2C (or SPI) interface. You just set the time once (like you do for any clock) and it keeps going on. From time to time you can request the current time. Personally I prefer the ones with a battery backup feature, so I can remove the power to the circuit without resetting it. Then I ask them the time once every day or at boot, so I keep synced.

Another way is to use NTP. NTP is a network protocol to synchronize times over a network (so you need an ethernet or wifi connection).

The third way is by using the radio signal used to synchronize radio clocks. For this you should investigate what radio clocks are active in your zone, then find a suitable transceiver and decode the signal you get.

And... Good luck! :)

Comment: So I already need to buy an extra hardware component to keep a clock? Depending on this information, I probably prefer the RTC with I2C interface, as I don't want NTP nor radio clocks.

Can you refer where I could buy this? Thanks!

Comment: Well, any RTC module is fine. You can find tons of them on ebay (usually they have a DS1307 or a newer DS3231 - for instance [this](http://www.ebay.it/itm/1PCS-Precision-DS3231-RTC-Module-Memory-Module-for-Arduino-Raspberry-Pi-/221921230883?hash=item33ab894023:g:OkAAAOSw~bFWKjgi) is really small); or even [sparkfun has a board](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/1270). As for me, I used a DS3232 for a project because I had one, but I made my own board.